# Android replace current fragment in tab layout and viewPager2

Tags: android

I want to keep viewPager2.setOffscreenPageLimit(4) to 4 and replace fragment from current tab.

viewPager2.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged(); doesn't work.

I'm using FragmentStateAdapter.